# SQL partition by with original order

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Here's the original MySQL table:

```
+----+-----+
| Id | Num |
+----+-----+
| 1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 3  |  1  |
| 4  |  2  |
| 5  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |
| 7  |  2  |
+----+-----+
```

When I use `select Id, Num, row_number() over(partition by Num) from t`, MySQL automatically disrupts the order of the `Num` column. However, I want to keep `Num` column order unchanged.
Specifically, the ideal output should be like:

```
+----+-----+-----+
| Id | Num | row |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  |  1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |  2  |
| 3  |  1  |  3  |
| 4  |  2  |  1  |
| 5  |  1  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |  1  |
| 7  |  2  |  2  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

How to write this MySQL query?

Comment: you can order by Id ?

Comment: @urlreader I think he's saying that the `row_number()` has to start over at 1 every time the original ordering goes to a new `Num`.

Comment: Do you have another column that distinguishes each group of rows? You can use that in the partition.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, I don't have other distinguishable columns.

Comment: You may have to go back to the old way of using a session variable to remember `num` from the previous line, and a `@row_number` session variable that gets incremented or reset to 1 depending on whether `num` changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. I would recommend using the difference between row numbers to identify the groups.

If `id` is always incrementing without gaps:

```
select id, num, 
    row_number() over(partition by num, id - rn order by id) rn
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by num order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

Otherwise, we can generate our own incrementing `id` with another `row_number()`:

```
select id, num, 
    row_number() over(partition by num, rn1 - rn2 order by id) rn
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by num order by id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebcb472fedef037544f648850add883c)** - for your sample data, both queries yield:

```
id | num | rn
-: | --: | -:
 1 |   1 |  1
 2 |   1 |  2
 3 |   1 |  3
 4 |   2 |  1
 5 |   1 |  1
 6 |   2 |  1
 7 |   2 |  2
```

Comment: It's probably unrealistic to assume no gaps in ID.

Comment: @Barmar: sure, and I edited with the alternative. I had to suggest that though, because it is more efficient to use `row_number()` just once in the subquery instead of twice.

Comment: One of these days I need to learn all the intricacies of window functions. We're still using 5.x at work, so I can't get any practice with 8.x features.

Comment: @Barmar: MySQL really came late to that party, while some other databases had that functionality for decades literally... There is a whole class of problem that window functions are very handy for. Typically, solving gaps-and-island without them is really chalenging.

Comment: @GMB As I mention in my comment above, they're not so hard using session variables.

Comment: @Barmar: true, but those are now planned for deprecation in future MySQL versions. I try to avoid them as much as possible in the answers I post...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [writing your own row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) to have greater control over its partitioning.

```
set @prev_num = null;
set @row_number = 0;

select
  id,
  -- Reset row_number to 1 whenever num changes, else increment it.
  @row_number := case
    when @prev_num = num then 
      @row_number + 1
    else
      1
    end as `row_number`,
  -- Emulate lag(). This must come after the row_number.
  @prev_num := num as num
from foo
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as the solution proposed by Schwern. Just another style of syntax in MySQL which I find very simplistic and easy to use.

```
Select
    id
  , num
  , value
from
(select
      T.id,
      T.num,
      if( @lastnum = T.num, @Value := @Value + 1,@Value := 1) as Value,
      @lastnum := T.num as num2
   from
      mytable T,
      ( select @lastnum := 0,
               @Value := 1 ) SQLVars
   order by
      T.id) T;
```

DB fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e04692841d091ccd54ee3435a409c67a